# What is the System.Guid part that is more likely to generate collisions if taken as subtring?

Tags: c#, guid

Which is the part of a System.Guid that is "less random"?

If I split my Guid in 8 parts, what is the part that gets more collisions on repeated calls to `System.Guid.NewGuid()`?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823

Comment: Why do you need to know? If you get a solid answer to this question, what do you intend to do with this knowledge? This sounds like a X/Y question. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Just make an ID and test the same and the same again for your demo calls, you do not need a `System.Guid`

As far as the `System.Guid` is concerned there is not any specific answer for the question which is the most repeated substring for a `Guid`